# titanium, save the state of last viewed window

Tags: javascript, titanium

I am wondering if there is a function for saving the last viewed window when a user quits the application, so when they go into the app again, it goes to the last viewed page, instead of restarting.  I have looked at Ti.App.Properties but haven't really found what I was looking for. Can anyone point me in the right direction, or if this is even possible.

Thanks

Comment: What did you not find out about properties that you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ti.App.Properties is the way to go.

If you are just looking to save which window the user was on, simply save the current window that the user is on every time the window changes.

If you want to save the current state, as your title suggests, you will also want to create a javascript object that holds all the data on the page, do JSON.stringify(object) and then save that string in a property as well.

Comment: This is for an assignment so actually I worded my question wrong, I'm not really looking for a function as that is kind of out of the scope for the assignment (at this stage). It is more about just saving the window so when the app re-starts it goes back to that last viewed window. How do I 'save the current window'?

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of code you can use to manage the state of the last opened window :

```
// Windows types
var TYPE_HOME = 'HomeWindow',
    TYPE_BLUE = 'BlueWindow';

// Properties' keys
var PROPERTY_LAST_OPENED_WIN = 'lastOpenedWindow';

// open the last opened window
var win = openLastWindow();

// Uncomment to open the blue window
// Then, comment and reopen the app => the blue window will be opened
//createAndOpenBlueWindow();

// Save the last window configuration
function setLastWindow(params) {
    Ti.App.Properties.setString(PROPERTY_LAST_OPENED_WIN, JSON.stringify(params));
}

// Create and open the last window opened
// (the function you have to call when you re-open the app)
function openLastWindow() {
    var params = JSON.parse(Ti.App.Properties.getString(PROPERTY_LAST_OPENED_WIN, '{}'));

    switch (params.type) {
        case TYPE_HOME: return createAndOpenHomeWindow();
        case TYPE_BLUE: return createAndOpenBlueWindow();
        default       : return createAndOpenHomeWindow();
    }
}

// Create a window with the given params AND
// save this window as last opened window
function createAndOpenWindow(params) {
    var win = Ti.UI.createWindow(params);
    setLastWindow(params);

    win.open();

    return win;
}

// Create windows of type "HomeWindow"
function createAndOpenHomeWindow() {
    return createAndOpenWindow({type:TYPE_HOME, backgroundColor:'#FF0000'});
}

// Create windows of type "BlueWindow"
function createAndOpenBlueWindow() {
    return createAndOpenWindow({type:TYPE_BLUE, backgroundColor:'#0000FF'});
}
```

This code creates and opens the last window opened thanks to the **openLastWindow** function.

The first time you open the app, the **Home** one will be opened (the **red**).

By **uncommenting** this line :

```
//createAndOpenBlueWIndow();
```

you will open the **BlueWindow** the next time you run the app.

Then, **re-comment this line**. The blue window will be opened (since it is the last opened).

Hope this helps !

Comment: thanks for that :-). I have my code all separated as per the MVC model. would I put the functions in the app.js file to make it global?